# Changing the dropdown list's value depending on textbox value

Tags: javascript, html

I m creating one web page having one textbox and one dropdown list with submit button.
Now my problem is :
When i ll enter text in a textbox depending on that text one sql 
query will run and it's result should be shown in drop down list.
I tried with onchange,onClick function but it didn't worked. I m not getting exactly how to retrive value from textbox.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't worked"? What exactly did you try, and what happened when you tried it? Was there an error message? It would be very helpful to be able to see some actual code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the onkeyup event - http://jsbin.com/elugo3/edit